# After restored in the MONERO GUI is showing a Different Primary Address - Zero Funds - what is happening

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed, ledger

I was checking my funds in my LEDGER NANO S, during almost 2 years was keep without any use. When I opened it a couple months ago, the Ledger Live ask for an Update Firmware, during the update was a 5 segs shutdown electricity and after that when a check MONERO APP was not anymore in the LEDGER.

BTC App was there and the funds OK.  
I was in shock and start looking for info to recover it. Then I found that the “right and easy way” was to download again the Monero APP in the ledger and make a restore the wallet from FILE. 
I included the 25 words for Monero SEED, I have tried like 10 times….
This is happening:

Balance = ZERO No history Transaction and after restore in the MONERO GUI is showing a Different Primary Address - My Ledger and my notes have a different primary Address. I have check several time the 25 words for Monero.
I have tried in different MAC computer + Monero GUI / also try the Feather Wallet. Nothing… My big concern is: why GUI is showing a different primary address? That mean wrong 25 words ? Wrong wallet ? lost funds at all or there is any chance?

Which options do I have ? Im so desperate, need some help on this, please

What about this : looks risky ahh? , I have really basic knowledge in crypto and programming
“there are python scripts that will let you view the actual Monero seed by taking in your ledgers 24 words and spitting out the mnemonic for your Monero”…